# MVC MapPageRoute and ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created a page route so I can integrate my MVC application with a few WebForms pages that exist in my project:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // register the report routes
    routes.MapPageRoute("ReportTest",
        "reports/test",
        "~/WebForms/Test.aspx"
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );
}
```

This has created a problem whenever I use Html.ActionLink in my Views:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") %>
```

When I load the page in the browser the link appears like:

```
http://localhost:12345/reports/test?action=Index&controller=Home
```

Has anyone run into this before? How can I fix this?

Comment: Alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10178276/11683

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you need to add some parameter options to the `MapPageRoute` declaration. So if you have more than one webforms page in the `WebForms` directory this works well.

```
routes.MapPageRoute  ("ReportTest",
                      "reports/{pagename}",
                      "~/WebForms/{pagename}.aspx");
```

*PS: You may also want to have a look at the `RouteExistingFiles` property of `RouteCollection`*

An alternative would be to use

```
<%=Html.RouteLink("Home","Default", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"})%>
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid using RouteLink just for brevity but I might have to end up using it. I just don't understand why the page route is getting matched with my regular routes when I use ActionLink.

Answer (score 6):

I just had a very similar issue. My solution was to give the routing system a reason to reject page route when looking for matches for the ActionLink.

Specifically, you can see in the generated URL that the ActionLink creates two parameters: controller and action. We can use those as a method to make our "standard" routes (~/controller/action/id) not match the page route.

By replacing the static "reports" in the page route with a parameter we'll call "controller" and then adding a constraint that the "controller" must be "reports" we get the same page route for our reports, but reject anything with a controller parameter that isn't "reports".

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // register the report routes
    // the second RouteValueDictionary sets the constraint that {controller} = "reports"
    routes.MapPageRoute("ReportTest",
        "{controller}/test",
        "~/WebForms/test.aspx",
        false,
        new RouteValueDictionary(),
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "reports"} });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );
}
```