# After add MapPageRoute to an asp.net mvc project, the site stops to enter in Home Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, webforms

I'm trying to route a .aspx (webforms page) in my asp.net mvc project. I register the page in global.asax:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapPageRoute("Tickets", "Reports/Tickets", "~/WebForms/Reports/Tickets.aspx");
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The problem is, after i add the second line, the site stops to enter in my Home Controller (Index Action) and is redirecting to: `http://localhost:37538/Reports/Tickets?action=Index&controller=Login%22` always that i run the project.

Project Details:

- Asp.Net MVC 3
- Forms Authentication
- .Net 4.0

Obs: to reproduce this error, create a new asp.net mvc project as internet app, after create the `Tickets` webforms page inside a `/WebForms/Reports` folder, and register the new route. Run the project (probably you're logged), so now logoff and you will be redirected to `http://localhost:35874/Reports/Tickets?action=LogOff&controller=Account`, so why?

Comment: Alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4441222/11683

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solved!** So, we need to add a route contraint to the webforms route to ensure that it only catches on incoming routes, not outgoing route generation.

Add the following class to your project (either in a new file or the bottom of global.asax.cs):

```
public class MyCustomConstraint : IRouteConstraint{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection){
        return routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest;
    }
}
```

Then change the Tickets route to the following:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "Tickets",
    "Reports/Tickets",
    "~/WebForms/Reports/Tickets.aspx",
    true, null, 
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "outgoing", new MyCustomConstraint() } }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issues where I couldn't log in to my pages anymore after adding a MapPageRoute. The submit-button on Login-page actually posted the values to the first page route. Do you have any source which describes this behavior and the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Here some links that help me to reach the solution: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/custom-route-constraint-aspnet, http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/MBest/archive/2010/01/06.aspx and http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/04/ASPNET-MVC---Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx

Comment: But specifically about you want, i don't have.

Comment: +1 for including your sources @ViniciusOttoni. This helped me out when I was about to just lose patience.

My issue was with calling MapPageRoute and MapRoute in the same solution on different projects; I was trying to use a mix of MVC and web forms. Hopefully this helps others in the same predicament.