# Integrating a WebForm into an MVC application ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

My question has 2 parts:

## 1

My MVC project has folder structure like so:

[image: folder structure]

I want to create a link in the 'Create' page that links to the 'Savings' `WebForm`

I've tried adding this to the RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
            "idea-savings-calculator",
            "Idea/Savings",
            "~/Views/Idea/Savings.aspx"
            );
```

but the default MVC MapRoute function:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

maps to the URL `localhost:xxxx/Idea/Savings` first and throws an error because there isn't an action called savings in the Idea controller Savings.

Edit: RouteConfig Class:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

                    routes.MapPageRoute(
            "idea-savings-calculator",
            "Idea/Savings",
            "~/Views/Idea/Savings.aspx"
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

## 2

Below is a cut from the 'Create' View of the 'Idea' Controller URL: `http://localhost:51946/Idea/Create`
[image: Idea>Create>]

(*red box indicates where I'd like the link to the Savings `WebForm`*)

The Savings `WebForm` is just a simple calculator; how would I pass the product from the calculations back to the above 'Create' page so that it can be displayed in the bottom text box? I'm guessing it would be as a parameter in the url that the Idea Controller can match? But... How?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your MapPageRoute come before your default MVC MapRoute? It needs to as the default is greedy.

Comment: If I put MapPageRoute first I get redirected to `http://localhost:51946/Idea/Savings?action=Index&controller=Idea` if I try to access any page under the Idea Controller

Comment: Have you looked at [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx) or [Glimpse](http://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse) to see what's happening with routing? I am successfully using routing very similar to yours to route friendly urls to legacy asp.net web forms. Maybe update your post with your complete RegisterRoutes method.

Comment: Forgot to ask, do you have `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");` at the start of your routing?

Comment: use IRouteConstraint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178276/after-add-mappageroute-to-an-asp-net-mvc-project-the-site-stops-to-enter-in-hom

Answer (score 1):

So to solve my first problem I moved the WebForms page 'Savings.aspx' to the route of my project and used the MapPageRoute **after** the MapRoute method.

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
"idea-savings-calculator",
"Idea/Savings",
"~/Savings.aspx"
);
```