# Using ASP.NET routing to serve static files (part 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I had similar problem as presented here: [Using ASP.NET routing to serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files)

In RouteConfig, I added the following lines:

> routes.Add(
>       "Images ABC", new Route("Images/abc/{*filename}", new ImageRouteHandler("abc")) );
>
> routes.Add(
>       "Images XYZ", new Route("Images/xyz/{*filename}", new ImageRouteHandler("xyz")) );

I found a pretty decent implementation of `ImageRouteHandler` here: http://www.phpvs.net/2009/08/06/aspnet-mvc-how-to-route-to-images-or-other-file-types/, I just added a parameter in the ctor to build the physical path...

Constraint: I have other paths in `Images`, beside of ABC or XYZ, that I don't want to be routed.

NOTE: I use `{*filename}` so I can refer to multiple segments... more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern

Questions:

1. Can I combine these 2 routes in 1 single statement without
   violate the constraint? maybe using somekind of regular expression
   such as `Images/[abc|xyz]/...`
2. The position matters. below or above the default routing.

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );

   - a) if the code is placed above of default routing, it will mess up
     the RedirectToAction
   - b) and if the code is placed below the default routing, it won't
     handle the immediate routing, ex. `Images/abc/img.jpg` won't be
     handled, but `Images/abc/level1/level2/level3/img.jpg` will be
     handled

Why? no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by:

- Adding a `IRouteConstraint`. That will 2 two things... only accept `IncomingRequest`, and check if the folder is abc or xyz. Source: [After add MapPageRoute to an asp.net mvc project, the site stops to enter in Home Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178276/after-add-mappageroute-to-an-asp-net-mvc-project-the-site-stops-to-enter-in-hom)
- Adding the following code above of default routing.

> routes.Add("Images Specials", new Route("Images/{folder}/{*filename}", null, new RouteValueDictionary { { "outgoing", new ImageRouteConstraint() } }, new ImageRouteHandler())
>       );

- Using a `ImageHandler` to make looking better.
  Source: http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2007/11/18/asp-net-mvc-framework-create-your-own-iroutehandler.aspx, and [Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)