# MVC 5 application won't process aspx file if RouteExistingFiles = true

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-routing

I have `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` in RouteConfig.cs in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. It won't process an aspx file. If I have try to open a URI like "/api/latest/Default.aspx" I get just some XML with these peculiar messages: 

`<Error>
  <Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:58341/api/latest/Default.aspx'.</Message>
  <MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'latest'.</MessageDetail>
</Error>`

The application has no problem serving up physical files. If I place an html file in the same directory it serves it up just fine. I have tried adding each of the following three lines to my RegisterRoutes:
`routes.IgnoreRoute("api");
routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");`

None of those worked.

It seems to be trying to route my URL to a route which looks like "api/{controller}" which is bizarre, because I don't have any routes which put a controller as the second argument! I've also tried commenting out all my routes - it still gives the same error message and won't process the aspx file.

I need to have RouteExistingFiles = true, because I am using this to provide authorization control for downloading certain files.

It seems like maybe I could add something to `<system.webServer><handlers>` to fix this but I don't know what.

Is there anyway I can get this working?

RouteConfig.cs:

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("api");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("api/*.aspx");

            routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your full RouteConfig.cs please?

Comment: Posted above, but the same thing still happens even if I remove all the routes.

Comment: I have a feeling that you may need to use `MapPageRoute`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178276/after-add-mappageroute-to-an-asp-net-mvc-project-the-site-stops-to-enter-in-hom