# MVC how to route aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello for an ecommerce replacement project, I have to route all old url to the new one (about 30.000 links).
I tried this solutions [After add MapPageRoute to an asp.net mvc project, the site stops to enter in Home Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178276/after-add-mappageroute-to-an-asp-net-mvc-project-the-site-stops-to-enter-in-hom) using placeholder to standardize the url

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
            "LegacyShop",
            "Error/_404",
            "~/it-www/{page}.aspx",
            true, null,
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "outgoing", new MyCustomConstaint() } }
        );
```

The "Error/_404" controller/action is a sample method that make a 301 to the new url based on a table.
But it's not working, every time I try I have a simple 404 error.
Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the URL in the browser? What are you expecting it to resolve to? What is it actually resolving it?

Comment: In the browser I have "//www.domain.com/page.aspx" and I need to redirect this to "//www.domain.com/controller/action", actually it resolve in a 404 error. I tried ti create a static aspx file, but it will continue to get 404 error