# Invalid url in form rendered by html.beginform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an application which is mix of WebForms and MVC.

HomeController is a simple controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

On view - `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`, I have used `Html.BeginForm` to render the form.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal"}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("username", "");
    @Html.Password("password", "");
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
}
```

Routes are configured like below.  First 2 routes are using MapPageRoute to map to webforms.

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
 routes.MapPageRoute("admin", "admin", "~/admin.aspx");
 routes.MapPageRoute("adminEdit", "adminEdit", "~/adminEdit.aspx");
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

But after my homepage ("Home" is my default controller) is rendered to the browser, form action has url:

> /admin?action=Index&controller=Home

not "/Home/" even though i have passed "Index" & "Home" as actionname and controllername to Html.Beginform respectively.

Url routing is working fine when i browse to my homepage. But the form's "action" has invalid url. It seems like it is matching the first route i have configured. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by following the instructions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441222/mvc-mappageroute-and-actionlink#4447439):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapPageRoute(
    routeName: "admin",
    routeUrl: "{pagename}",
    physicalFile: "~/{pagename}.aspx");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

However, I cannot explain why the parameter is necessary to make it not match in this case.

Comment: I agree with you. i noticed parameters are must to have this work properly. I cannot have your first rule in my application as only admin.aspx and adminEdit.aspx supposed to have this rule (extensionless url), other pages have other rules. so i split them into 2 static parameterless rules. But the thing that is weird to me is why Html.beginform match with the parameterless rule. I removed these 2 rules and handled them through url rewriting.